# How to make only the overlapping part of two overlapping images responsively transparent?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I used `clip-path` to overlap the two images and make only the overlap transparent:

```css
.bg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
}

.image-red {
  position: absolute;
  top: 150px;
  left: 150px;
  clip-path: polygon(0px 0px, 150px 0, 150px 50px, 50px 50px, 50px 150px, 0 150px);
}

.image-green {
  position: absolute;
  top: 200px;
  left: 200px;
  clip-path: polygon(100px 0, 150px 0, 150px 150px, 0 150px, 0 100px, 100px 100px);
}
```

```html
<img class="bg" src="https://via.placeholder.com/500/ffffff/888888/500x500.png">
<img class="image-red" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150/ffeeee/ff8888/150x150.png">
<img class="image-green" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150/eeffee/008800/150x150.png">
```

However, this does not work if the image is placed in `%`, `vw`, `vh`...

I don't want to use JavaScript if possible, is this a solution to this problem in CSS (or JavaScript)?

Comment: Are the images' sizes static?

Comment: @Richard Image's size isn't static. There is a possibility that is set an images that size is larger or smaller.

Comment: My answer below accounts for non-static size of images.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that it is possible to use pure CSS to do the above, but if someone has a solution using pure CSS, please do share ;-)

As for my solution, here's the minimal working example (adjust the position of the two images arbitrarily to see the effect).

```js
let redImage = document.querySelector('img.image-red')
let greenImage = document.querySelector('img.image-green')
let redImageRect = redImage.getBoundingClientRect()
let greenImageRect = greenImage.getBoundingClientRect()

function returnIntersectionPoints(rectOne, rectTwo) {
  let intersectionLeft = Math.max(rectOne.left, rectTwo.left)
  let intersectionTop = Math.max(rectOne.top, rectTwo.top)
  let intersectionRight = Math.min(rectOne.right, rectTwo.right)
  let intersectionBottom = Math.min(rectOne.bottom, rectTwo.bottom)

  if (intersectionLeft < intersectionRight && intersectionTop < intersectionBottom)
    return {
      left: intersectionLeft,
      top: intersectionTop,
      right: intersectionRight,
      bottom: intersectionBottom
    }
  else
    return false
}

function returnClipPathPolygon(rect, clippedRect) {
  let horizontalClip = rect.left === clippedRect.left ? 'left' : 'right'
  let verticalClip = rect.top === clippedRect.top ? 'top' : 'bottom'
  let polygonPoints = []

  if (horizontalClip === 'left' && verticalClip === 'top') {
    polygonPoints.push([clippedRect.right, clippedRect.bottom])
    polygonPoints.push([clippedRect.right, clippedRect.top])
    polygonPoints.push([rect.right, rect.top])
    polygonPoints.push([rect.right, rect.bottom])
    polygonPoints.push([rect.left, rect.bottom])
    polygonPoints.push([clippedRect.left, clippedRect.bottom])
  }
  else if (horizontalClip === 'right' && verticalClip === 'top') {
    polygonPoints.push([clippedRect.right, clippedRect.bottom])
    polygonPoints.push([rect.right, rect.bottom])
    polygonPoints.push([rect.left, rect.bottom])
    polygonPoints.push([rect.left, rect.top])
    polygonPoints.push([clippedRect.left, clippedRect.top])
    polygonPoints.push([clippedRect.left, clippedRect.bottom])
  }
  else if (horizontalClip === 'left' && verticalClip === 'bottom') {
    polygonPoints.push([rect.right, rect.top])
    polygonPoints.push([rect.right, rect.bottom])
    polygonPoints.push([clippedRect.right, clippedRect.bottom])
    polygonPoints.push([clippedRect.right, clippedRect.top])
    polygonPoints.push([clippedRect.left, clippedRect.top])
    polygonPoints.push([rect.left, rect.top])
  }
  else if (horizontalClip === 'right' && verticalClip === 'bottom') {
    polygonPoints.push([rect.right, rect.top])
    polygonPoints.push([clippedRect.right, clippedRect.top])
    polygonPoints.push([clippedRect.left, clippedRect.top])
    polygonPoints.push([clippedRect.left, clippedRect.bottom])
    polygonPoints.push([rect.left, rect.bottom])
    polygonPoints.push([rect.left, rect.top])
  }

  let polygonString = 'polygon('
  polygonPoints.forEach(point => {
    polygonString += `${point[0] - rect.left}px ${point[1] - rect.top}px, `
  })
  polygonString = polygonString.substring(0, polygonString.length - 2)
  polygonString += ')'
  return polygonString
}

let intersectionPoints = returnIntersectionPoints(redImageRect, greenImageRect)
if (intersectionPoints) {
  redImage.style.clipPath = returnClipPathPolygon(redImageRect, intersectionPoints)
  greenImage.style.clipPath = returnClipPathPolygon(greenImageRect, intersectionPoints)
}
```

```css
.bg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
}

.image-red {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10%;
  left: 20%;
}

.image-green {
  position: absolute;
  top: 25%;
  left: 15%;
}
```

```html
<img class="bg" src="https://via.placeholder.com/500/ffffff/888888/500x500.png">
<img class="image-red" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150/ffeeee/ff8888/150x150.png">
<img class="image-green" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150/eeffee/008800/150x150.png">
```

Basically, what I'm doing is:

- Find intersecting points of the two rectangles (if intersection does occur) using the function `returnIntersectionPoints`.
- If there is an intersecting point, I will call the function `returnClipPathPolygon` to form the `polygon` string value to pass to clip-path for each of the images.

---

**EDIT**

The above code fails when one image can totally encompass the other image. Also, the `returnClipPathPolygon` function is a bit lengthy. As a result, I came up with a new idea to deal with said problems:

- Get the intersection points of the two rectangles
- Create a replica `bg` that acts as an overlay. This replica is clipped to a shape based on the intersection points (always will be a rectangle)
- Use that replica bg to cover the other two images (by using `z-index`), thus making the two images appear transparent (when it's really not)

Here's the working example below:

```js
window.onload = (() => {
  let redImage = document.querySelector('img.image-red')
  let greenImage = document.querySelector('img.image-green')
  let redImageRect = redImage.getBoundingClientRect()
  let greenImageRect = greenImage.getBoundingClientRect()

  function returnIntersectionPoints(rectOne, rectTwo) {
    let intersectionLeft = Math.max(rectOne.left, rectTwo.left)
    let intersectionTop = Math.max(rectOne.top, rectTwo.top)
    let intersectionRight = Math.min(rectOne.right, rectTwo.right)
    let intersectionBottom = Math.min(rectOne.bottom, rectTwo.bottom)

    if (intersectionLeft < intersectionRight && intersectionTop < intersectionBottom)
      return {
        left: intersectionLeft,
        top: intersectionTop,
        right: intersectionRight,
        bottom: intersectionBottom
      }
    else
      return false
  }

  function returnClipPathInset(rect, intersectionPoints) {
    let insetTop = intersectionPoints.top
    let insetRight = rect.right - intersectionPoints.right
    let insetBottom = rect.bottom - intersectionPoints.bottom
    let insetLeft = intersectionPoints.left
    return `inset(${insetTop}px ${insetRight}px ${insetBottom}px ${insetLeft}px`
  }

  let intersectionPoints = returnIntersectionPoints(redImageRect, greenImageRect)
  if (intersectionPoints) {
    let bg = document.querySelector('img.bg')
    let bgRect = bg.getBoundingClientRect()
    let bgReplicaOverlay = document.createElement('img')
    let clipPathValue = returnClipPathInset(bgRect, intersectionPoints)

    bgReplicaOverlay.classList.add('bg')
    bgReplicaOverlay.src = bg.src
    bgReplicaOverlay.style.zIndex = 2
    bgReplicaOverlay.style.clipPath = clipPathValue

    document.querySelector('body').prepend(bgReplicaOverlay)
  }
})
```

```css
.bg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
}

.image-red {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10%;
  left: 10%;
}

.image-green {
  width: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 15%;
  left: 12.5%;
}
```

```html
<img class="bg" src="https://via.placeholder.com/500/ffffff/888888/500x500.png">
<img class="image-red" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150/ffeeee/ff8888/150x150.png">
<img class="image-green" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150/eeffee/008800/150x150.png">
```

*The two codes above do not handle window resizing.*

Comment: Thank you for a clear example.I read the code, how does this work? In my Firefox and Chrome, the condition of the `returnIntersectionPoints` function always returns `false`.

Comment: @EdBuckner Are you sure it always returns false? In my browser, it's working correctly.

Comment: @EdBuckner Perhaps it's because your document has not loaded and the JS has run. Try adding window.onload to wrap JS.

Comment: @EdBuckner I've added `window.onload` on the second code snippet, please do try it out.